# setup proxy in Kali Linux

Tags: kali-linux, xfce, proxy

I need to configure a proxy in kali Linux xfce to derive all my applications through the internet, I have tried export http_proxy but in this way only the terminal takes the internet and I have tried to configure the browser, I want everything to be derived through the proxy and all my programs have internet